# Compare rows in a group in R

Tags: r

I would like to be able to compare rows in a dataframe I have.

The idea is that I should compare rows where the id number is the same and the `VisitDate` column is different by  maximum of three days. I want to take the row with the later date rather than the earlier one.

My data frame:

```
id     Date

1      12/05/06
1      16/05/06
1      17/05/06
4      12/05/06
4      13/05/06
3      12/05/06
5      12/05/06
66     12/05/06
66     13/05/06
66     19/05/06
66     24/05/06
66     25/05/06
```

The data frame I want is

```
1      17/05/06
4      13/05/06
66     13/05/06
66     25/05/06
```

The code so far is:

```
library(dplyr)
    arrange(id, as.Date(data$Date, '%d/%m/%y')) %>%
            #Search where two rows have the same hospital number
      group_by(id) %>%
      slice(which.max(Date))
```

but this doesn't return the correct data.

Comment: Don't think I got it. Why the row `66 - 19/05/06` is excluded from the output?

Comment: That's excluded because the rows to compare should be no more than three days apart for the same id

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for the case sample, maybe it will work for your data.
Data used:

```
data=data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,4,4,3,5,66,66,66,66,66),
                Date=as.Date(c(1,5,6,1,2,1,1,1,2,8,13,14),origin = "2006-05-11"))
```

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  mutate(Diff=Date-lag(Date),n=n())%>%
  filter((Date==max(Date) | Diff<3)&n>1 )%>%
  select(id,Date)
     id       Date
  <dbl>     <date>
1     1 2006-05-17
2     4 2006-05-13
3    66 2006-05-13
4    66 2006-05-25
```

The idea is to create a column with the difference between 2 dates using `lag()` and filter on this column as well as the date and the number of dates per id.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

data = read.table(header = T, text = "
  id     Date
1      12/05/06
1      16/05/06
1      17/05/06
4      12/05/06
4      13/05/06
3      12/05/06
5      12/05/06
66     12/05/06
66     13/05/06
66     19/05/06
66     24/05/06
66     25/05/06
           ")

setDT(data)[, Date := dmy(Date)]

data[, Diff := {
  lagged = shift(Date, n = 1, type = "lag")
  delta = Date - lagged
}, by = id][Diff <= 3 & Diff > 0, .(id, Date)]
```